# Emulate steering wheel from a generic controller / other joystick peripheral

Tags: windows-10, emulator, game-controller, controller

So I've scraped together a humble (non-motion-plus) WiiMote and scripted a trusty script in Freepie:

```
# In different places of earth this number will vary, however it is estimated to be 9.81.
accelOverride = 5.25
    
# Log the acceleration value - when placed above a flat surface it should log as a number below 0.8
diagnostics.watch(wiimote[0].acceleration.x-accelOverride)
diagnostics.watch(wiimote[0].acceleration.y-accelOverride)
    
# Define a variable that should help manipulating the Wiimote's X/Y-axis acceleration
# Note: LR is Left/Right and UD is Up/Down
accelLR = wiimote[0].acceleration.y-accelOverride
    
# Establish a small deadzone that should help with the inconsistency of the acceleration of Earth
if accelLR < 0.7 and accelLR > -0.7:
    accelLR = 0
        
# Now log our accel values - the post-processed acceleration value
diagnostics.watch(accelLR)
    
# Now calculate everything
angleLR = filters.ensureMapRange((accelLR), 8, -8, vJoy[0].axisMax*-1, vJoy[0].axisMax)
    
vJoy[0].x = angleLR
```

which basically makes the Wiimote a steering wheel by taking the acceleration values of it and maps it to the x-axis of a (virtual controller's) left-stick. All this is good, however some games only allow you to have a controller input and no keyboard input at the same time. So I was wondering: Is there a software or way to emulate a steering wheel from a fully-working (virtual, shouldn't make a difference) controller?

Comment: Likely, yes. The question you have asked has now been answered. If you are just asking a theoretical question, please note that Superuser is not for theoretical questions, generally. If you have a more specific question, please use the EDIT button to focus your question and clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I've edited my post to clarify that I was asking about software / is there a way to do it. Sorry for the lack-of-clarity.

Comment: you still asked a question that has a simple `yes` answer  ... there is a difference between `is there a way to paint the fence blue?` and `what do i have to do to paint the fence blue?`